# Problems running Sitecore 7.2 in Azure

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-azure

I have a running two Sitecore 7.2 web sites in Azure where one is Test and other is Prod. The sites are copies of each other where only difference is the Prod has a public URL. They use same the same DB and usr/pwd.

After copying everything from Test to Prod the Prod site has starting throwing errors after user tries to log on to Sitecore. Looks like Sitecore tries to create a support ticket but I am not able to figure out what the error really means. 
Any help is appreciated.

This is Error Message

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Sitecore.Support.400292.400293.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Sitecore.Support.400292.400293.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Sitecore.Support.400292.400293.dll' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Sitecore.Support.400292.400293.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +102
   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile) +34
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.LoadAssembly(String name) +222
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(String assembly, String className, Object[] parameters) +11
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(String typeName, Object[] parameters) +126
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.ReadCommands() +467
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager..cctor() +50

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager' threw an exception.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommand(String name) +0
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.GetCommand(String message) +69
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddMenuItem(Control parent, Item child, String target, CommandContext context) +181
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddFromDataSource(Item item, Control parent, String target, CommandContext context) +355
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.AddFromDataSource(Item item, String target) +52
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContextMenu.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +57
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not creating a support ticket, it's literately saying what you need to know. It's missing a file and it expects that file to be found at D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Sitecore.Support.400292.400293.dll

Check your configuration files for this dll. To me it seems like a web.config transformation gone wrong (since sitecore support DLLs usually don't include 2 issue numbers.

Comment: Well yes it turns out that Sitecore was indeed missing the file. But it was however not refereed from any config files, rather Sitecore.Kernel.dll had included this Security patch dll.